# How to group piped commands to process with a wrapper function

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write myself a logging function for my bash shell. My goal is to have the function that can preface a command and will pass the stdout and stderr of the command to dated logfiles. Currently I have:

```
logme()
{
    FULL_COMMAND=$@

    for EXE in ${FULL_COMMAND}
    do
        case $EXE in
            nohup) continue;;
            time) continue;;
        esac
        break
    done

    mkdir -p logs
    LOGNAME=$(basename ${EXE})_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S)

    echo $FULL_COMMAND > logs/${LOGNAME}.e.log
    echo '============' >> logs/${LOGNAME}.e.log
    $FULL_COMMAND > logs/${LOGNAME}.o.log 2>> logs/${LOGNAME}.e.log
}
```

This seems to work for simple cases. Running:

```
$ touch file1.txt
$ touch file2.txt
$ touch file3.txt

$ logme ls -lh
```

produces a logs directory with 2 dated files.

```
$ more logs/ls_2017-05-08_16\:05\:36.e.log 
ls -lh
============

$ more logs/ls_2017-05-08_16\:05\:36.o.log 
total 6.5K
-rw-r--r-- 1 aholman compbio  0 May  8 16:05 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 aholman compbio  0 May  8 16:05 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 aholman compbio  0 May  8 16:05 file3.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 aholman compbio 92 May  8 16:05 logs
```

However, adding pipes in the command doesn't behave as I'd hoped. The logging seems to group with the first command, and the output of logme is passed through the pipe. Of course, there is no output from logme because the whole purpose is to direct it to files.

```
$ logme ls -lh | grep -v file2
$ more logs/ls_2017-05-08_16\:12\:15.e.log 
ls -lh
============

$ more logs/ls_2017-05-08_16\:12\:15.o.log 
total 6.5K
-rw-r--r-- 1 aholman compbio  0 May  8 16:05 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 aholman compbio  0 May  8 16:05 file2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 aholman compbio  0 May  8 16:05 file3.txt
drwxr-xr-x 2 aholman compbio 92 May  8 16:12 logs
```

Is there a good way to group the whole command such that the entire thing gets processed by logme?

Comment: You could put it in `{ …; }`, not sure whether there will be side effects though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Not sure if I understand the syntax you're suggesting. `{ logme ls -lh | grep -v file2 ; }` has the same effect as illustrated above. `logme { ls -lh ; }` fails with a bash syntax error.

Comment: FYI, I'd also be open to a solution that modifies the `logme` script. I'm not married to that code.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is processing the command line before your script sees it. It only passes what remains after that processing (that command before the pipe). To bypass such
processing you need to quote the whole command:

```
logme 'ls -lh | grep -v file2'
```

You have a new problem though. The command is in a string and you can't execute it
directly. One way to do it is with eval

```
eval "$FULL_COMMAND" > logs/${LOGNAME}.o.log 2>> logs/${LOGNAME}.e.log
```

But eval should be used with caution as it is easily exploitable: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048